# How to change Edge Home Page

Tags: microsoft-edge, homepage

I want to change MS Edge browser home page

I don't want the default Edge news page.

I followed the instructions were given by Google but did not work for me

[image]

I turned on the Home Button as suggested

[image]

and set a new home page

[image]

but I still get the standard MS home page !!

[image]

How to change the default home page in edge?

Comment: Set the new home page you want in the second last screen. I do that on all machines and Edge opens exactly where I want.

Comment: @John I Tickets the "New tab page" but still the same!

Comment: Try repairing Edge (Windows, Settings, Apps, select Edge, Repair

Comment: Go to *Settings > Start, home, and new tabs*, under "When Microsoft Edge starts" set "Open these pages" to checked, then verify that your page is shown. If not there, click the 3-points icon, select Edit, enter your home URL and click Save. Did this help?

Comment: @harrymc thanks, put that as an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to set the Home page for Microsoft Edge :

- Go to *Settings > Start, home, and new tabs*
- Under "When Microsoft Edge starts" set "Open these pages"
  to checked
- Verify that your page is listed
- If it's not there :

  - Click the 3-points icon and select Edit
  - Enter your home URL
  - Click Save.

To set this URL as the New Tab page requires an extension : [Custom New Tab](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/custom-new-tab/onagfgjlokaciajhjmajljcfanonbmia).
In this extension's options you may set the URL for the
New Tab.

Comment: it worked for home page when i first open the browser,
but new tabs still using MS news page

Comment: I added this to my answer.

Comment: @asmgx I have the same issue, though I set the URL in _Custom New Tab_ to a local HTML file, which in my case was `file:///D:/temp/hp.html`. Perhaps _Custom New Tab_ has a constraint on using local files with _file_ protocol (although Edge opens my home page with that local file)?